# Trying to use NER (Named Entity Recognition), but I can't get the server running

Tags: java, python-3.x, github, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I've been following the instructions from this github repo: https://github.com/caihaoyu/sner. I installed NER from the official website: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html, and then installed the latest version of Java (JRE). However, when I try to get the NER server up and running, using the command in the sner repo readme, I get this error: Could not find or load main class .ext.dirs=..lib.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentation for using the Stanford CoreNLP server:

Overall info: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html

Server info: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Sample command to start server:

```
java -Xmx12g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000 -serverProperties myProperties.props
```

in `myProperties.props` you should set

```
annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner
```

Sample server request:

```
wget --post-data 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"outputFormat":"json"}' -O -
```